# How to keep my vehicle upgrades equipped on Jetpack Joyride?

Tags: android, jetpack-joyride

Everytime I start the game I have to re-equip ALL my vehicle upgrades. The gadgets are fine, the issue is only with the vehicles. I've already tried to backup my save and reinstall the game, but it didn't solve my problem. I'm running it on Android 2.3.6. Any suggestions?

Comment: As you have a back up of the save. I would suggest trying a brand new start. To see if the same issue persists. I know it will take a little while to obtain the upgrades. But at least it would tell you if it is some errant bug in the game, or some nutty quirk with just that save file. Furthermore,  if the issue does carry on after that test. Then follow up with the developer via email. Which you can get through the jet pack joyride Google play page. I have only played it on an ipad. So I couldn't tell you if awesome123 is on the right track or not.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bug. Try logging into facebook of something, wait four days, then delete the game, and re downloading it

Comment: Hmm.. Why four days? Why not three? Or 38573?